# Searching items in array and making new variables out of them

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Suppose I have an array like this `array('first item', 'seconditem', 'third item')` 
Now i want to search for all items in the variable (using `foreach` , as im assuming i dont know how many items will be inside the array)
How would i remove all spaces and add them to a new array, with pretty much the same structured, but they would appear as:

```
array('firstitem','seconditem','thirditem')
```

instead of:

```
array('first item', 'seconditem', 'third item')
```

in PHP by the way..

Comment: You know enough to use `foreach`, so attempt a solution and post it here. You're expected to at least *try* to solve your problem before asking for help.

Comment: yes but the problem is im not sure what the function is called that deals with searching for things in the character and removing them ;/ im honestly not just asking to be fed code, i really am trying to learn how i would handle arrays like this.

Comment: @user3332590: It's called `str_replace`. And it directly supports arrays, so you don't even need the `foreach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
function removeSpaces($input) {
    foreach (array_keys($input) as $i) {
        if (is_string($input[$i])) {
            $input[$i] = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $input[$i]);
        } elseif (is_array($input[$i])) {
            $input[$i] = removeSpaces($input[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $input;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$array = array('key1' => 'test item', array('first item', 117 => 'seconditem', 'third item'));

$array = removeSpaces($array);

print_r($array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [key1] => testitem
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => firstitem
            [117] => seconditem
            [118] => thirditem
        )

)
```

**This function works recursive and secure with custom keys! :)**

Comment: there we go, preg_replace() is what i was looking for, no need to do loop as i can just use foreach though, thanks

Comment: @ReeCube: No need for a loop at all: `$input = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $input)`.

Comment: @Jon yes a loop isn't needed but if you want that your script works with arrays and objects too, your way will trow an exception, **this function is the secure way to solve the problem**

Comment: @ReeCube: The only problem being that "recursive" is not in the question. Also, this is far from "the secure way" to solve the problem because it won't work with arrays that have string keys, or even numeric keys that are not consecutive, or numeric keys that are negative. And finally, at the time I posted that comment your own solution wasn't recursive anyway (although it was still buggy regarding the array key issue). Recommend reading more and talking less.

Comment: @Jon I updated it, now it's recursive and with custom key. Ah and i recommend same for you, because your code can throw exceptions and this is bad! But if you have other notes for me, just tell it.

Comment: @ReeCube: Great! Now for the next version, read the documentation on `foreach` because it can provide you the keys directly: `foreach($input as $key => $i)`. I also recommend reading the documentation on `preg_replace`, because it would never throw exceptions. In fact, *no global PHP function throws any exceptions under any circumstances* (at least until now).

Comment: @ReeCube: Also, note that [my own suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354040/searching-items-in-array-and-making-new-variables-out-of-them#comment33976871_22354040) was for `str_replace`, which has no problem with nested arrays (it doesn't recurse, but that's it). [See it with your own example](http://ideone.com/lUlZ3u), and let's stop here because I don't have more time to waste.

Comment: No exceptions, right?
`<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected 'print_r' (T_STRING) in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>18</b><br />`

Comment: @ReeCube: 1) that's not an exception, 2) syntax errors in *your* code are *your* problem, not mine, 3) we 're done here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49575/discussion-between-reecube-and-jon)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$arr = array('firstitem', 'second item', 'third item');
array_walk($arr, function(&$value, $key) { $value = str_replace(' ', '', $value); });
print_r($arr);
```

Gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => firstitem
    [1] => seconditem
    [2] => thirditem
)
```

If you don't want the original array to be changed, copy it first (`$arr2 = $arr`);